# Collecting Moran's I output values in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I am running an iterator in ModelBuilder that ultimately takes the output from each iteration (a point feature class) and runs the spatial auto-correlation tool (global Moran's I).  I have about 450 output feature classes, and what I would like to have is the feature class name, index value, z-score, and p-value from each iteration (of Moran's I) added as a new record in a table.  These values are reported in the .HTML report and the model run summary window, but I can't figure out how to extract them and add them to a table.

If I were doing this with a statistical model in R, I could simply call the model output values (index, p-value, etc.).  But Ideally I would like to do this in ModelBuilder.  I'm not opposed to writing a Python script, but before I go down that road I'm wondering if there's a more direct way to do it with existing geoprocessing or ModelBuilder tools.

As an additional note, I would also like to get the default calculated bandwith from the Kernel density tool output to a table similar to the Moran's I values.

I am running ArcGIS Pro 2.3.

Answer (score 3):

Using the arcpy implementation of the [spatial autocorrelation tool](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-statistics/spatial-autocorrelation.htm), you can get this information. Albeit, in a somewhat roundabout way.

Firstly, as per the documentation (example 2), if you set a variable called `moransI` to the actual call of the tool such as:

```
moransI = arcpy.SpatialAutocorrelation_stats("olsResults.shp", "Residual",
                        "NO_REPORT", "GET_SPATIAL_WEIGHTS_FROM_FILE", 
                        "EUCLIDEAN_DISTANCE", "NONE", "#", 
                        "euclidean6Neighs.swm")
```

You'll get access to the getMessages function. This contains the full output text of the tool. And it's ugly:

*"Start Time: Thursday, 21 March 2019 3:32:00 PM\nRunning script SpatialAutocorrelation...\nWARNING 001605: Distances for Geographic Coordinates (degrees, minutes, seconds) are analyzed using Chordal Distances in meters.\nWARNING 000846: 58 feature(s) had no neighbors which generally invalidates the statistical properties of a test.\nWARNING 000847: Features with no neighbors (only includes first 30): FID = 1186, 6475, 6634, 6712, 7563, 10078, 13157, 13518, 13941, 14496, 15894, 17155, 17156, 17195, 17363, 17365, 20442, 20986, 21047, 21171, 21350, 23587, 26744, 28141, 28153, 28615, 28982, 30519, 30520, 30768.\n\n Global Moran's I Summary \nMoran's Index:   0.210751  \nExpected Index:  -0.000018 \nVariance:        0.000001  \nz-score:         176.055455\np-value:         0.000000  \n\nDistance measured in Meters\n\nCompleted script Spatial Autocorrelation (Global Moran's I)...\nSucceeded at Thursday, 21 March 2019 3:32:26 PM (Elapsed Time: 26.01 seconds)"*

However, you can create a list for each line of text like so:

```
moranList = moransI.getMessages().split('\n')
```

Then, you can get all the summary values by accessing those items in the list:

```
moranIndex = moranList[-10]
ExpectedIndex = moranList[-9]
Variance = moranList[-8]
zScore = moranList[-7]
pValue = moranList[-6]
```

Of course, this will have some unwanted text, which I'll leave as an exercise. You'll just want to pull out the numbers from the strings.